# What is the most effective way to refresh token in Nestjs APi

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, token, nestjs

I am consuming a third party API that requires authentication to be refreshed every 24 hours. The auth endpoint returns a token and expiration date. If the refresh is not done within 24 hours then I have to get a new token. So I need to get the current date and compare it with the expiration date in less than 24 hours.

According to documentation, it's advisable to save the token in the DB then use it for every request. So I have to manually pass the ID to fetch the token.

1. Is there a better way to do this.
2. I want to refresh the token in less than 24 hours, maybe 23 hours to the time of the expiry date. I tried to compare the current and the expiration date but `let esfgesrfsd` is returning `Invalid Date`

This is the expiration date format `"2020-07-20T11:32:13.025Z"`
This is the current date format `'Sat, 18 Jul 2020 20:48:45 GMT'`

```
  async ManageAuth() {

        const tokenId = "5f1346459662c133f02hyt23";
        const savedToken = await this.AuthToken.findById(tokenId)

        let stringDate = savedToken.tokenExpirationTime.toString();
        var dateTime = new Date();
        let CurrentTime = dateTime.toUTCString();

        let esfgesrfsd = new Date(stringDate).toUTCString();

        if (esfgesrfsd < CurrentTime) {
            await this.RefreshAuthToken();
        }
        else if (esfgesrfsd > CurrentTime) {
            this.Auth()
        }
        return savedToken
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, you must compare `Date` objects rather than their string representation (`new Date(isoStringA) < new Date(isoStringB)`). To answer your 2nd point, you might want to use Task Scheduling: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, every 23 hours the cron is supposed to call the auth endpoint but I got ```Exception has occurred: TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined``` I am using axios post request.

Comment: Cron job didnt work with AXIOS. refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63039361/how-to-fix-typeerror-cannot-read-property-post-of-undefined-on-axios-with-nes/63039712#63039712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Frozn

I was able to fix it with the below code. The token will expire in 48 hours, but I want to re-auth before the next 24 hours so I have to deduct 26 hours. so the re-auth will happen every 22 hours. I am still open to a better implementation

```
    async ManagePrimeTimeAuth() {

        const tokenId =process.env.token;
        const savedToken = await this.AuthToken.findById(tokenId)

        let DBExpirationDateTime = Date.parse(savedToken.tokenExpiration.toString());
        var CurrentdateTime = new Date();

        let CurrentdateTimeMinus2 = CurrentdateTime.setHours(CurrentdateTime.getHours() - 26);
        let CurrentdateTimeMinus2Con = new Date(CurrentdateTimeMinus2).toISOString();


        let ExpirationDateTime = new Date(DBExpirationDateTime);
        let CurrentDateTimeMinusTwoHr = new Date(CurrentdateTimeMinus2Con)


        if (ExpirationDateTime < CurrentDateTimeMinusTwoHr) {
            const Primetimeauth = await this.PrimetimeAuth()
            return Primetimeauth
        }
        else if (ExpirationDateTime > CurrentDateTimeMinusTwoHr) {
            return savedToken

        }
        return this.PrimeTimeRefreshAuthToken()

    }
```