# How to fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined on Axios with Nestjs cronjob

Tags: node.js, cron, axios, httprequest, nestjs

I tried using cron scheduler to get authentication token every 15 sec(Test purpose) the cron is supposed to call the auth endpoint but I got `Exception has occurred: TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined`

```
 @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_15_SECONDS)
    async handleCron() {
        //const Primetimeauth = this.PrimetimeAuth()

        const primeAuth = await this.httpService.post('https://clients.com/api/auth', {
            "username": process.env.username,
            "password": process.env.password
        }).toPromise();

        if (primeAuth.status != 200) {
            throw new HttpException({
                message: `Vending Authentication Failed`,
                statusCode: primeAuth.status
            }, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        const data = primeAuth.data;

        await this.PrimetimeAuthToken.updateOne({ "_id": "3dtgf1341662c133f0db71412drt" }, {
            "$set":
            {
                token: data.token,
                tokenExpirationTime: data.expires,
                timeTokenReceived: new Date
            }
        });

        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the entire class? is the class `@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })`? Does it have any dependencies that are scoped to request scope?

Comment: The class is large, yes I have ``` @Inject(REQUEST) private request: any ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron expressions do not work with Request scoped providers, due to possibly being run outside of the context of the request. Due to this, all dependencies come in as `undefined`. To fix this, you'll need a non-request-scoped provider.